# WPF OnStartup exception

Tags: c#, wpf

I have an WPF app that is used by around 70 people. And one user asked me to help him with a problem. He reinstalled Windows 10 x64 and since then his copy just crashes  when closing the splash screen. I sent him a version with logging to see what is happening inside `App.xaml.cs` (`OnStartup` method). Loggin works only on the first line. I tried to surround the whole method content with a `try-catch` block, and this what I found:

> Exception.Message: Category does not exist.
>
> Exception.Source: System

Could this be due to a broken .NET framework after reinstalling Windows?

App.xaml.cs:

```
    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            logger.Info("Startup function1");
            if (Process.GetCurrentProcess().Parent().ProcessName == "cmd")
            {
                logger.Info("Program shutted down");
                Process.GetCurrentProcess().Kill();
            }
            logger.Info("base.OnStartup");
            base.OnStartup(e);
            logger.Info("base ended");
            logger.Info("setting culture");
            CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
            CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
            logger.Info("setting culture end");
            IoC.Setup();
            logger.Info("IOC Setted up");
            Current.MainWindow = new MainWindow();
            if (e.Args.Length > 0 && e.Args[0] == "-usb")
            {
                logger.Info("Usb sended");
                (Current.MainWindow as MainWindow).Usb = e.Args[1];
            }
            logger.Info("Window showing");
            Current.MainWindow.Show();
        }
        catch (Exception exp)
        {
            logger.Info("Error: " + exp.Message + " Source: " + exp.Source);
        }
    }
```

UPD commented code:

```
public static class ProcessExtensions
{
    private static string FindIndexedProcessName(int pid)
    {
        var processName = Process.GetProcessById(pid).ProcessName;
        var processesByName = Process.GetProcessesByName(processName);
        string processIndexdName = null;

        for (var index = 0; index < processesByName.Length; index++)
        {
            processIndexdName = index == 0 ? processName : processName + "#" + index;
            var processId = new PerformanceCounter("Process", "ID Process", processIndexdName);
            if ((int)processId.NextValue() == pid)
            {
                return processIndexdName;
            }
        }

        return processIndexdName;
    }

    private static Process FindPidFromIndexedProcessName(string indexedProcessName)
    {
        var parentId = new PerformanceCounter("Process", "Creating Process ID", indexedProcessName);
        return Process.GetProcessById((int)parentId.NextValue());
    }

    public static Process Parent(this Process process)
    {
        return FindPidFromIndexedProcessName(FindIndexedProcessName(process.Id));
    }
}
```

Comment: This exception seems to occur in context of PerformanceCounters. Do you use PerformanceCounters?

Comment: I'd also recommend you to always log `Exception.StackTrace` (or usually just the entire `Exception.ToString()`) so that no one had to guess where that exception had been actually thrown.

Comment: The application obviously breaks on this line `Process.GetCurrentProcess().Parent().ProcessName == "cmd"`. What is `Parent()`? It is not a member of `Process`. I only know `Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName`.

Comment: Try to use `if (Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName == "cmd")` instead.

Comment: Like @BionicCode said, please explain this `Parent()` method since that is not a standard method on the `Process` class.

Comment: @DavidBentley this method gets a parent process of application (if it exist).
App 100% throws an exception not there, because i commented all method and sended to user version without it, and it still shutting down.

Comment: @KlausGütter nope, i didn't use that.

Comment: @EugenePodskal i'll wait for user to get more information about exception.

Comment: @KlausGütter alrigth about the PerfomanceCounter you were right. It was used in extension method Parent(). But i removed all traces of this method and commented overrided OnStartup, app still closing. Now i don't have any ideas where i can place try catch to log what happens.

Comment: Show us the code where you commented everything out. Are you passing anything into StartupEventArgs? Are you using any Nuget packages?

Comment: @DavidBentley added the code to post.